How to change light bulb in flat mounted lamp
I can't figure out how to change the lightbulb in this lamp.  The metal "nut" isn't a shape that can be easily gripped, and is very stuck--I'm not sure it is even meant to be turned.  Thanks in advance for any help!


If the profile of the fixture is the same all the way around, with nothing on the opposite side that's not shown in the picture, then the center nut is the release.
I've had fixtures like that, and one unscrews the nut to remove the frosted glass cover.
It is possible to tighten the nut with pliers so hard you need pliers to get it off again.
Hold the glass with one hand and get pliers on the nut with the other hand. Turn the nut in the usual lefty-loosey-righty-tighty fashion to remove the nut - counterclockwise while looking up at the nut. Keep hold of the glass while the nut loosens, then carefully take the glass off. Reverse to put the glass back on. You shouldn't use pliers to tighten the nut this time.

Thanks I managed to rotate it with a piece of silicone!  Then there was a small piece of metal underneath the cap that also had to be unscrewed to release the glass.
